# Please figure out how this Checksum was derived

Tags: crc, checksum

I have hexadecimal data from first 5 blocks of T5557 125KHz RFID card. The 5th block appear to be some kind of checksum which I like to know how it is derived.

Below are 11 different samples of the data. Rows 1 to 5 in the tables represent block 1 to 5 of T5557 125 KHz RFID card.

(1)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 79 68 E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | ED 13 60 29 |

(2)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 81 68 E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 67 ED 6E A2 |

(3)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 7A 6A E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 67 42 43 F4 |

(4)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 82 6A E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | A4 1C 39 4B |

(5)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 83 6A E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | AF DB 05 31 |

(6)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 7B 6C E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 7C 90 DD F8 |

(7)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 84 6C E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 9E 9F B5 FA |

(8)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 7C 6E E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 26 35 F2 7B |

(9)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 85 6E E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 59 40 B0 E4 |

(10)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 7E 62 E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 98 D7 99 2D |

(11)

| Block | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Block 1 | C9 09 8C F1 |
| Block 2 | 00 01 01 01 |
| Block 3 | 8D 62 E1 0B |
| Block 4 | 00 E1 13 00 |
| Block 5 | 94 E0 6E 12 |

Please note how changes in block 3 column 1 data  for samples 1,2,3 and 4,5 and 6,7 and 8,9 and 10,11 affect block 5 data.

Is anyone able to figure out how data in row 5 was derived?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read about how to reverse a CRC? E.g. https://hackaday.com/2019/06/27/reverse-engineering-cyclic-redundancy-codes/

Comment: Please add more details as to what algorithms have you tried? Why do you think its a checksum? Any other correlation that you have done?

Comment: @sudhackar many thanks for your response. I have tried using CRC calculator at http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html. I think it is a checksum because of the way a single byte change in block 3 affects the data (block 5)